# How to load data in Meteor App using Redux?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, redux, react-redux

**Intro:**

So I have been struggling with Redux for quite a bit. I think I do understand the concept now. In essence (and quite simplified):

1. There is a **Store** that holds all your Apps relevant state,
2. User interactions with the App can trigger **Actions** that have a
   descriptive title and some data payload
3. **Reducer** use the current state from **Store** and the **Actions** payload to put updated state in the store (on top of old state)

Now this is nice because one can connect components (even deep down in the react tree) with the state and use the state as a single source of truth (i.e. always knowing if a user is logged in or not).

*My problem with this comes when combining Redux with Meteor and I am still not clear about why and what information one would want to put into the Redux store in a Meteor app.*

---

**Example**:

Say we have a collection of posts. Typically we would just get the via Minimongo and show the results to the user. Now lets say we want to have our Redux store as a single source of truth to hold all the data. One would essentially have to synchronize minimongo with the Redux store.
Presumably one would on the componentDidMount dispatch an action to load data into the store.

```
store.dispatch({
  type: 'GET_POSTS',
  posts: Posts.find().fetch(),
});
```

This would then be reduced to:

```
const postReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_POSTS':
      return action.posts;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Now to keep this store up to date it would have to be synced with the Posts collection, presumably like this (although I am not entirely sure where in my code I would have to place that tracker):

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  store.dispatch({
    type: 'GET_POSTS',
    posts: Posts.find().fetch(),
  });
});
```

**Now my main question is:** How does one avoid massive bloating of the Redux store, because the way I understand it whenever somebody submits a new post we would have the current state + a new state (which is essentially the current state + the new post).
If you have a few people posting back and forth this could explode quite fast, or even if your initial number of posts is large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:
Also to address the main question from above. One should (in the majority of cases) not put data from Mongo into the store, but rely on native meteor functionalities. For an example see below.

> **Solution:**
>   Not tested, but should work. Below is a way displayed to get data from Mongo in a Meteor App based on Redux state.

**Update:**
Tested something similar in the meantime. Switched Step 2 and 3. This was necessary, because otherwise one couldn't access the filter in createContainer. (Since it's a bit of an "from the outer component to the inner component logic" when composing components)

> **1. Setup PostsList (to display posts):**
>
> ```
> class PostsList extends Component {
>     render () {
>         return (this.props.posts.map((post,i) => {return (<div key={i}>post.header</div>)})
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **2. Hook up component to Meteor:**
>
> ```
> const PostsListContainer = createContainer((props) => {
>     let posts = Meteor.subscribe('getPosts', props.filter);
>     return {
>         posts
>     }
> }, PostsList)
> ```
>
> **3. Connect component to Redux:**
>
> ```
> const mapStateToProps = state => {return{filter: state.filter}}
>
> const ConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps,)(PostsListContainer)
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for asking this! Last week I during a training I learned about React + Redux, and I was eager to add it to Meteor. Boy, do I find myself in quite the rabbit hole ever since!

I'm aware that you've already gotten familiar with Redux. For those who didn't, you should definitely check [these videos](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux).

As I've [written earlier](https://github.com/nqbao/meteor-react-redux-example/issues/6#issuecomment-311734675),

> I've become aware of two issues. These issues
>   arise when you let all data (including Collections) flow through the
>   Redux Store:
>
> 1. You loose out on Meteor reactivity (with vanilla Meteor, when the MongoDB updates, the data shown in the View also updates). Solution:
>      We could write additional Redux actions & reducers on the server-side.
> 2. You loose out on Meteor optimistic UI (with vanilla Meteor, when you would add a new Widget, the client will already try to predict
>      what it should look like even before the server responds). In the
>      example here, while calling a Redux action (e.g. to add a Widget), we
>      essentially wait for the Meteor method to insert the Widget in the
>      collection before moving onto the Reducer which will update the Redux
>      Store, who's State in turn updates our View. (Of course, all of this
>      happens so quickly that you wouldn't notice it, but you might notice
>      it if you were running it on a slow server or when you'd have a mobile
>      application). Solution: We could write additional logic in the actions
>      that update the Store immediately with the new Widget, and if it turns
>      out we weren't authorized to call the Meteor method, we can still use,
>      within the Action, the `.catch` of the Promise to adjust the Store
>      (removing the Widget we already added).
>
> So basically, by introducing Redux into our Meteor-React solution,
>   we're missing out on two great features of Meteor. Both of them can be
>   rebuilt using self-written logic, but it frankly seems a shame to do
>   so.

The way I currently see it:

- For relatively simple apps where you don't have to manage a lot of state, just don't introduce Redux to your React-Meteor stack. You'll find yourself writing a lot more extra code (i.e. for optimistic UI and server-sided changes). Code which Meteor normally takes care of in the first place.
- For more complex apps with a lot of state management: Redux simply seems to be one of the best ways to currently handle this for React apps. In this case it might be worthwhile to treat Meteor just as a server. Calls to the MongoDB should then always go through Meteor methods, which in turn are called from within Redux actions. Meteor methods should definitely not be called from within Redux reducers, because that would be a [side effect](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect). *At this point you may wonder what the advantage is of still using Meteor - and that is a very good question.*

Asides that I've been thinking about an architecture that tries to combine the best of two worlds. Such an architecture would still use Meteor's subscribe/publish functions (so you get to keep optimistic UI and server-sided changes going to the client), and would use Redux Store for UI specific changes (think filter buttons).

A more concrete example: You get your toDos through Meteor publish/subscribe inside your app. But before you actually render them to your component, you stick a filter function in the middle. This filter function is dependent on whatever the Redux Store has to say about filters. This in turn is defined by some buttons you pressed, which were passed on to the Redux Store through Redux actions & reducers.

Comment: I think I do agree with your more concrete example. What you describe there makes sense to me and is kind of where I arrived now with my thinking. Would you be able to put that down in writing (pseudo code is fine)? The way I see it is that you would create a container (i.e. createContainer from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';), within that container you would subscribe to your relevant subscription and after that filter the data based on props you get from your redux store, right?

Comment: Was about to post it in a comment but first I wanted to test the approach. I have done this in the meantime, but I see a very good answer has already been provided!

Perhaps good to add for people who're looking for more explanation on how not to bloat the Redux Store, is basically to keep UI State and Domain State separate as a guiding principle! How to is explained in this series (the 5th article is not linked in the row but you can google it): https://medium.com/front-end-developers/how-we-redux-part-1-introduction-18a24c3b7efe

Comment: However now it makes me wonder how to manage user information, and whether to put it in the Store or simply pass it down to components as props: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852424/how-to-manage-meteor-user-in-meteor-react-redux-setup